# Graph theory - Show that T has at least 2 vertices with deg(v)=1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> So, i am going to show that, by using $$(T5): |E|=|V|-1$$ that the
>   tree T has at least two vertices with degree 1.

---

**My attempts so far:**

We know that the sum of all degrees of a tree with n vertices over all v is

$$ \sum\limits_{v}deg(v)=2|E|=2(n-1)$$
Furthermore, we know that the number of vertices is
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}V_i=n$$
there $V_i$ is the number of vertices with degree i. This means that $deg(v)=iV_i$ and by that we can rewrite the first sum as
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}iV_i=2|E|=2(n-1)$$
Now, if we subtract the second sum from the sum above, we will get
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}(i-1)V_i = 2(n-1)-n = n-2$$

Here it takes stop for me. And i am not clearly sure why i should subtract the second sum from the first one. The first one is the sum of all degrees over vertices v and the second one is the sum of all vertices $V_i$ with the degree i,namely the number of vertices in the tree. But what does this subtraction gives me? and how can i show that at least 2 of the verticec has degree 1?

Comment: No dice, an isolated vertex is a tree and has *no* vertices of degree 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of the subtraction is that $V_1$ does not contribute to the sum (because $i-1=0$ for $i=1$), whereas all $V_i$ with $i>1$ contibute *at least* with a factor of one. In fact, I would subtract twice and in the other direction:
$$ V_1\stackrel{(1)}\ge \sum_{i\ge1} (2-i)V_i=2n-2(n-1)n=2$$
where $(1)$ holds because on the right hand side, $V_1$ occurs with a factor of $2-1=1$ as on the left, and all other (nonnegative!) $V_i$ are added with a factor $2-i\le 0$, so cannot cause an increase.

---

*Remark:* What about vonbrands comment? Well, the above implicitly assumes that $V_0=0$. Strictly speaking we should start the summation at $i=0$, which then only gives us
$$ 2V_0+V_1\ge \sum_{i\ge0} (2-i)V_i=2n-2(n-1)n=2$$
i.e.: $V_0\ge 1$ or $V_1\ge 2$.

Comment: if i take (i-2) i will get

$V_1 = 2 + V_3 + 2V_4 + \dots$

Since $V_i$>=0 this tells us that $V_i$>=2 ?